# Check if element already exist within template class

Tags: c++, templates, equality

I have built a class called Set which inherits from the base-class called ISet and it looks something like this.

```
template <class T>
class Set : public ISet<T>
{
public:
    Set();
    ~Set();
    Set(const Set &origin);
    Set operator=(const Set &origin);

    bool insert(T element);
    bool remove(T element);
    int size()const;

private:
    T *arr;
    int cap, nrOfElement;

    void deepCopy(const Set &origin);
    void freeMemory();
};
```

I should now build the function called insert, which should insert a element of type T if, and only if, it does not exist already.
I'm having a problem to understand how to solve this since T element should be able to be of any type. 
I have tried something like:

```
bool Set<T>::insert(T element)
{
    bool added = false;

    if (nrOfElement == 0)
    {
        this->arr[0] = element;
        this->nrOfElement++;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->nrOfElement; i++)
        {
            if (this->arr[i] == element)
            {
                i = this->nrOfElement;
                added = true;
            }
        }
        if (added == false)
        {
            this->arr[nrOfElement++] = element;
        }
    }

    return added;
}
```

But since some of the classes I'm trying to insert as T doesn't have the operator==, it can't handle the == operation above I try to do.
Should I try to type_cast it? Or how do you solve this?

Comment: Generally, you would require the implementation of `operator==`, otherwise, how could you know if two elements are the same?

Comment: Typically the type `T` is required to define `operator<` (in the case of `std::set`) or `std::hash<T>` (in the case of `std::unordered_set`). If the type `T` is not somehow comparable how are you supposed to check if it exists in your container?

Comment: Can you give an example of a type that doesn't implement `operator==`, which you would want in this container that guarantees no duplicates?  There's something of a contradiction in this question, in that you want no duplicates of a type and the type is unable to detect duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Either

1. Document that your template works only with types that are equality comparable or
2. Store a function object within your template class that can be used to compare the objects. The type of the comparison object needs to be a template argument. You can default to `std::equal_to<>`, which will use `operator==` unless specialised. The user must provide a custom comparison object in order to use the template with non-equality-comparable types. This is how standard containers deal with comparisons. If the user cannot implement such comparison object, then there is no way to know whether one object is a duplicate of another.

Comment: afaik standard containers rarely use `==` but rather `<` and `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` to check for equivalence (at least thats what `std::set` and `std::map` do)

Comment: @idclev463035818 `std::map` compares for inequality because it orders the elements `std::unordered_map` uses equality for example.

Comment: didnt know about equality for `std::unordered_,map`, thanks, I'll have a look